# I am working on a project and I need to translate speech into text I used Expo and React-native-voice

Tags: reactjs, react-native, expo, speech-to-text, react-native-voice

I am working on a project and I need to translate speech into text I used Expo and React-native-voice.
**[Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object (evaluating 'Voice.onSpeechStart = null')]
- node_modules\react-native-voice\src\index.js:23:10 in removeAllListeners
- node_modules\promise\setimmediate\core.js:37:14 in tryCallOne
- ... 9 more stack frames

```js
import React from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableOpacity } from "react-native";
import Voice from "react-native-voice";
import * as Permissions from "expo-permissions";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      results: [],
    };
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStart;
    Voice.onSpeechRecognized = this.onSpeechRecognized;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = this.onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = this.onSpeechPartialResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = this.onSpeechVolumeChanged;
  }
  async componentDidMount() {
    const {status} = await Permissions.askAsync(
      Permissions.AUDIO_RECORDING
    );
  }
  componentWillMount(){
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners)
  }



  onSpeechStart = (e)=> {
    console.log('onSpeechStart',e);
    
  };
  onSpeechRecognized =(e)=>{
    console.log('onSpeechRecognized',e); 
  }
  onSpeechEnd = (e)=>{
    console.log('onSpeechEnd'+e);
  }
  onSpeechError =(e)=>{
    console.log('onSpeechError'); 
  }
  onSpeechResults =  e => {
    console.log('onSpeechResults'+e);
    this.setState({
      results: e.value,
    });
  }
  onSpeechPartialResults = e =>{
    console.log('onSpeechPartialResults' + e.value);
  }
  onSpeechVolumeChanged = e =>{
    console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged');
  }
  _startRecognizing=async()=>{
    try{
      await Voice.start('en-US')
    } catch(e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
  _stopRecognizing = async()=>{
    try{
      await Voice.stop()
    }catch(e){
      console.error(e);
      
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this._startRecognizing}
          style={{
            backgroundColor: "green",
            height: 40,
            width: 100,
            marginBottom: 10,
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ 
            fontSize: 20, 
            alignSelf: "center" 
            }}>
              Starts
              </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <TouchableOpacity
          onPress={this._stopRecognizing}
          style={{ 
            backgroundColor: "red", 
            height: 40, 
            width: 100 
          }}
        >
          <Text style={{ 
            fontSize: 20, 
            alignSelf: "center" 
            }}>
              Stop
              </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});
```

from framework internals**

Answer (score 2):

## Update for Expo 41+

With the release of the Expo SDK 41, [config plugins](https://docs.expo.dev/guides/config-plugins/) were added. The [3.2.0 release](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice/releases/tag/v3.2.0) of `react-native-voice/voice` added support for config plugins.

You install the dependency as you normally would

`yarn add @react-native-voice/voice`

And then you must update your `app.json`

```
"expo": {
  "plugins": [
    [
      "@react-native-voice/voice",
      {
        "microphonePermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to access your microphone",
        "speechRecogntionPermission": "Allow $(PRODUCT_NAME) to securely recognize user speech"
      }
    ]
  ]
}
```

You will probably need to create a new build as you may get an invariant violation.

You should now read the documentation for [usage](https://github.com/react-native-voice/voice#usage)

—-

## Expo 40 and older

Unfortunately `react-native-voice` is not compatible with Expo.

The reason for this is that Expo abstracts the native iOS and Android code away from you, this makes it quick and easy to make builds and develop but the downside is that you cannot add dependencies that require you to use native code.

`react-native-voice` requires the use of native code. You can see this by the fact that the installation instructions require you to link the native code. See [here](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-voice/blob/master/README.md#linking) for the documentation.

If you wish to use this dependency in your Expo project then you will need to eject it. You can find more info about ejecting, and the pros and cons of doing so on the Expo documentation website [here](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/expokit/eject/)

Answer (score 1):

With Expo SDK42 you can use the `react-native-voice` plugin, here is what they have in the docs [here](https://docs.expo.dev/clients/getting-started/#customizing-your-runtime)

Answer (score 0):

I have the same issue developing an react native app with react-native-voice package. I followed every step of the workflow (like instructed in the react-native-voice documentation as well as suggested by other answers), there seems nothing wrong -
`expo run:android` build successful. Then `expo start --dev-client` on my android emulator/physical device both throw this error:

> [Unhandled promise rejection: TypeError: null is not an object
> (evaluating 'Voice.isSpeechAvailable')]

In the end, I found that, one needs to open two terminals in vscode, one terminal running `exp start` (while connecting to your device), and the other terminal simultaneously runs `expo run:android`.

The app then is running on the device like a charm!
Hope this helps, and hope someone can explain more on this regarding how react-native/expo test development works?