# react-native-voice package for react-native app giving an error

Tags: react-native, expo, speech-to-text, react-native-community, react-native-voice

I am building a react-native app on **windows** and testing it on **physical android device**. The basic purpose of the app is to convert speech into text. I am using @react-native-voice library. First I created the app with

```
npx react-native init myapp
```

But on pressing the record button, it gives an error/warning of

> cannot read properties of undefined( reading 'startSpeech)

Similarly I got the same warning for stopSpeech, destroySpeech etc.

After hectic search, I moved to **expo-cli** for creating the react-native app. But facing the same error again. Expo community expert says that expo has added the @react-native-voice into its **expo-SDK > 41**. You just have to add the **plugins** section into your **app.json**. plugin thing is explained in this [stackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58040614/i-am-working-on-a-project-and-i-need-to-translate-speech-into-text-i-used-expo-a) post
I have tried everything but nothing is working.

The code is attached below

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  Image,
  TouchableHighlight,
} from 'react-native';

import Voice, {
  SpeechRecognizedEvent,
  SpeechResultsEvent,
  SpeechErrorEvent,
} from '@react-native-voice/voice';

type Props = {};
type State = {
  recognized: string;
  pitch: string;
  error: string;
  end: string;
  started: string;
  results: string[];
  partialResults: string[];
};

class App extends Component<Props, State> {
  state = {
    recognized: '',
    pitch: '',
    error: '',
    end: '',
    started: '',
    results: [],
    partialResults: [],
  };

  constructor(props: Props) {
    super(props);
    Voice.onSpeechStart = this.onSpeechStart.bind(this);
    Voice.onSpeechRecognized = this.onSpeechRecognized;
    Voice.onSpeechEnd = this.onSpeechEnd;
    Voice.onSpeechError = this.onSpeechError;
    Voice.onSpeechResults = this.onSpeechResults;
    Voice.onSpeechPartialResults = this.onSpeechPartialResults;
    Voice.onSpeechVolumeChanged = this.onSpeechVolumeChanged;
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    Voice.destroy().then(Voice.removeAllListeners);
  }

  onSpeechStart = (e: any) => {
    console.log('onSpeechStart: ', e);
    this.setState({
      started: '√',
    });
  };

  onSpeechRecognized = (e: SpeechRecognizedEvent) => {
    console.log('onSpeechRecognized: ', e);
    this.setState({
      recognized: '√',
    });
  };

  onSpeechEnd = (e: any) => {
    console.log('onSpeechEnd: ', e);
    this.setState({
      end: '√',
    });
  };

  onSpeechError = (e: SpeechErrorEvent) => {
    console.log('onSpeechError: ', e);
    this.setState({
      error: JSON.stringify(e.error),
    });
  };

  onSpeechResults = (e: SpeechResultsEvent) => {
    console.log('onSpeechResults: ', e);
    this.setState({
      results: e.value,
    });
  };

  onSpeechPartialResults = (e: SpeechResultsEvent) => {
    console.log('onSpeechPartialResults: ', e);
    this.setState({
      partialResults: e.value,
    });
  };

  onSpeechVolumeChanged = (e: any) => {
    console.log('onSpeechVolumeChanged: ', e);
    this.setState({
      pitch: e.value,
    });
  };

  _startRecognizing = async () => {
    this.setState({
      recognized: '',
      pitch: '',
      error: '',
      started: '',
      results: [],
      partialResults: [],
      end: '',
    });

    try {
      await Voice.start('en-US');
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  _stopRecognizing = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.stop();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  _cancelRecognizing = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.cancel();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  };

  _destroyRecognizer = async () => {
    try {
      await Voice.destroy();
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
    this.setState({
      recognized: '',
      pitch: '',
      error: '',
      started: '',
      results: [],
      partialResults: [],
      end: '',
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <Text style={styles.welcome}>Welcome to React Native Voice!</Text>
        <Text style={styles.instructions}>
          Press the button and start speaking.
        </Text>
        <Text style={styles.stat}>{`Started: ${this.state.started}`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.stat}>{`Recognized: ${
          this.state.recognized
        }`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.stat}>{`Pitch: ${this.state.pitch}`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.stat}>{`Error: ${this.state.error}`}</Text>
        <Text style={styles.stat}>Results</Text>
        {this.state.results.map((result, index) => {
          return (
            <Text key={`result-${index}`} style={styles.stat}>
              {result}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
        <Text style={styles.stat}>Partial Results</Text>
        {this.state.partialResults.map((result, index) => {
          return (
            <Text key={`partial-result-${index}`} style={styles.stat}>
              {result}
            </Text>
          );
        })}
        <Text style={styles.stat}>{`End: ${this.state.end}`}</Text>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._startRecognizing}>
          <Image style={styles.button} source={require('./button.png')} />
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._stopRecognizing}>
          <Text style={styles.action}>Stop Recognizing</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._cancelRecognizing}>
          <Text style={styles.action}>Cancel</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
        <TouchableHighlight onPress={this._destroyRecognizer}>
          <Text style={styles.action}>Destroy</Text>
        </TouchableHighlight>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  button: {
    width: 50,
    height: 50,
  },
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  action: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#0000FF',
    marginVertical: 5,
    fontWeight: 'bold',
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
  stat: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#B0171F',
    marginBottom: 1,
  },
});

export default App;
```

Thank you in advance for the help :)